# Dropdown Menu CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my dropdown menu. When I over over the main level link, the drop down appear but at the left of my screen instead of underneath the main link.
I have been on this for a couple of hours and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html part :

```html
<div class="nav">

        <ul id="menu">
           <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Apetiziers</a>
              <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Entree</a>
             <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
             </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Main Course</a>
             <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
             </ul>      
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Dessert</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
             </ul>      
              </li>


              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

 </div>
```

And the .css :

```css
ul#menu {
   float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px;
    background: #333; color: #fff;
    line-height: 100%;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline; 
}


/* top level link */
ul#menu a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: #789; color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

/* main level link hover */
ul#menu a.current {
  background: #f60; color: #fff;
}


ul#menu li:hover > a {
  color: #fff; background: #ff4500;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* dropdown */
ul#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block; /* shows the sub-menu (child ul of li) on hover */
}

/* sub level list */
ul#menu ul {
    display: none; /* hides the sub-menu until you hover over it */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

ul#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #9BB3BF; color: #036;
}

/* sub levels link hover */
ul#menu ul li a:hover {
color: #036; background: #DDDF99;
}
```

Comment: you can try this demo : http://www.themeswild.com/read/horizontally-centering-drop-down-using-pure-css

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to change the CSS style, why not think of doing something like this. Why not try with this CSS style?

#### HTML

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```css
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)

Comment: @Starx Good question. To stop reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Starx There's no difference from the OP's code. He has to understand the CSS and apply accordingly. Check both the mark up.

Comment: How will he understand, you have not explained anything? Why would this fix the problem and what wrong did he do?

Comment: No need of using `float` and `position` here. Well, do you understand CSS?

Comment: If that is the your question then No Praveen, I do not understand CSS.

Comment: @Starx Then how do you understand my answer. Simple. :)

Comment: I don't still understand what's your point. Coz, I don't want the OP to change the markup, but the style he's using is quite not right. So, I suggested the right one, which is compatible with all the browsers. Dude, I don't find anything wrong in down voting my answer! Anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably jumping towards the closest relative container. So configure your list to act as relative container:

```css
ul#menu > li {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also there was unnecessary `float` in your anchor tags, your li are already set to display as `inline` there is no point in float them

```css
ul#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Here your [fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Gfdy/)

Comment: HI, I did try that but now the drop down menu appears on the right side of the furthest right main link...

Comment: @wizzme, I was hoping you could fix the rest. Check my update for the fiddle with the fix

Answer (score 0):

If cannot want use : `position:relative`, then use : `left:auto;` instead : `left:0;`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KAGhL
But position relative will be usefull and will give ability to set z-index to keep menu on top of other element

Comment: sorry, I am not sure I understand your answer

Comment: or you use position:relative on parent <li> and left:0; on submenu, or just use left:auto on submenu and display:inline-block on <li>. if you give : position:relative:z-index:1; submenu will always show on top of other content. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your floats on the parent elements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's best if you provide a short snippet of code demonstrating the solution. Thanks!